# Автоматическое подключение к интернету в Linux (systemd) через PPPoE (rp-pppoe)

Tags: linux, pppoe, systemd

Недавно в Симферополе подключился к провайдеру FarLine, который, к сожалению, раздаёт интернет в частном секторе только через pppoe. Это мне с самого начала, ещё до подключения не понравилось, но альтернатив для моего района просто нет, разве что через телефон.

С самой настройкой проблем не возникло. Запустил `sudo pppoe-setup` и там в интерактивном режиме указал пользователя, интерфейс (enp0s10) нашёлся модем `Found a RFC 2516 compliant modem, congratulations! :)`, demand value  последствии указываю `no`, так как при `yes` никогда не удавалось подключиться, DNS когда оставлял по умолчанию, когда перезаписывал гугловскими, на это никак не влияло на ход подключения, пароль указывал, в последствии в файле `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` контролировал правильность логина и пароля, и фаервол отключаю 0. Честно говоря зачем и как в pppoe фаервол на уровне подключения понятия не имею. У меня и так iptables (SuseFirwall2) запущен, все интерфейсы определены как внешние, и открыты только нужные и используемые мною порты, так что смысла в ещё одном фарволе не вижу.
И вот долгожданная команда `sudo pppoe-start`, которая должна была меня осчастливить, но впоследствии принесла только разочарование, и нервозность после более нескольких десятков пересоздания конфигов через `pppoe-setup` и попытки подключиться, а после заставить её работать в юните systemd. :-(

Дело вот в чём. Когда я успешно подключился первый раз через `pppoe-start` мне она в stdout выдавала, на первый взгляд корректную активность. Но во все последующие разы, с любыми конфигурациями и любым результатом подключения, консоль выдаёт теперь только это.

```
sudo pppoe-start
................TIMED OUT
/usr/sbin/pppoe-start: line 193:  3719 Terminated              $CONNECT "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

При этом иногда подключение устанавливается во время пинга (появляющиеся точки вначале), а иногда нет, но вывод консоли теперь всегда только такой, который в конце завершается таймоутом, даже если соединение успешно установлено. :-(

Казалось бы, ну и пёс с ним, пусть себе что хочет выдаёт, главное, ведь, подключение устанавливается и не разрывается, но не тут-то было.
Я же хочу, что бы оно автоматически устанавливалось и создаю в `systemd` юнит `/usr/lib/systemd/system/pppoe.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=PPPoE <--> ppp0 over enp0s10
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppoe-start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/pppoe-stop
PIDFile=/var/run/pppoe.conf-pppoe.pid.pppoe

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

В дальнейшем я пробовал и типы `single`, и `oneshot`. Перепробывал не все типы, но результат 1. При запуске сети (`wicked`), подключение устанавливается, но после получение таймаута от процесса `pppoe-start`, `systemd`, как от него и ожидается и вполне корректно и правильно, убивает к чёртовой матери все дочерние процессы, и как следствие подключение. Ему же и в голову, точнее в алгоритм, не может прийти, что это нормальное поведение этого процесса и так и должно быть, как в прочем и мне.

Пробовал удалить папки `/etc/ppp` и `/etc/ppp.d` и переустановить пакеты `ppp` и `rp-pppoe`, и заново настроить через `pppoe-setup`, но результат был аналогичный.

Вот содержимое конфигурационного файла `/etc/ppp/pppoe.conf` очищенный от комментариев.

```
ETH='enp0s10'
USER='my_correct_login'
DEMAND=no
DNSTYPE=NOCHANGE
PEERDNS=no
DNS1=
DNS2=
DEFAULTROUTE=yes
CONNECT_TIMEOUT=30
CONNECT_POLL=2
ACNAME=
SERVICENAME=
PING="."
CF_BASE=`basename $CONFIG`
PIDFILE="/var/run/$CF_BASE-pppoe.pid"
SYNCHRONOUS=no
CLAMPMSS=1412
LCP_INTERVAL=20
LCP_FAILURE=3
PPPOE_TIMEOUT=80
FIREWALL=NONE
LINUX_PLUGIN=
PPPOE_EXTRA=""
PPPD_EXTRA=""
```

Мне кажется, что-то блокирует определение соединения на оборудовании провайдера, а может у меня не правильно настроен `pppoe`.

Помогите разобраться в этом вопросе, и/или подскажите как правильно для такого кривого случая написать `systemd` юнит, что бы он выполнял автоматическое подключение и не разрывал его при получении таймаута от родительского процесса?

Любую конфигурационную информацию для анализа ситуации без проблем предоставлю. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался! :-)

`rp-pppoe` использует утилиты `netstat` и `ifconfig` для анализа сети.
Они всё ещё предоставляются в openSUSE в пакете `net-tools-deprecated`.

`sudo zypper in ppp rp-pppoe net-tools-deprecated`

С `demand=yes` по прежнему не работает, но теперь с `demand=no` скрипт `pppoe-start` выдаёт радостную строчку 'Conected!' и завершается. :-)

А следовательно `systemd oneshot true` и все дела! :-)

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/pppoe.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=PPPoE <--> ppp0 over enp0s10
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppoe-start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/pppoe-stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable pppoe.service && sudo systemctl start pppoe.service`

Answer (score 1):

В SUSE, начиная с версии 12, консольные инструменты для pppoe сломаны. Чинить их не собираются и всех отправляют в NetworkManager.

Comment: Именно только в Suse? А если rp-pppoe из исходных кодов собрать, или дело не только в этом пакете?

Comment: И не ужели никто из этих "отправителей"  не посоветовал просто выполнить `sudo zypper in net-tools-deprecated`?
Хотя для русскоязычного форума openSUSE это обычное дело, собственно именно по этому я тему создал здесь, а не там.

Comment: @Ilya Indigo дело в том, что вы сделали какой-то велосипед. Стандартным решением до 12 версии была настройка этого дела через yast. В 12 версии настройку через yast сломали и послали всех в NetworkManager. 
Ваш велосипед решает данную проблему  в обход yast, вот и все.